# Using OnkeyDown as an if condition Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use `.onkeydown` to restrain my input field. I wrote this function, but I'd like to use it in an `if condition`, to check if entry keys are right or wrong.

But I don't know how form should I use in my `if` to call this function, because actually it's not really an Angular scope function, but a JS one...

```js
var cpNumber = document.getElementById("cpNumber");                 
cpNumber.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
        || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58)
        || ((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
        || (e.keyCorde == 65)) 
        || ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
        || (e.keyCode == 65))
        || ((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) 
        || (e.keyCorde == 66)) 
        || ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58)
        || (e.keyCode == 66))
        || e.keyCode == 8) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
                        
                        
// If condition, check if entry keys are wrong. 
// I tried cpNumber.onkeydown(e), but the "e" 
// seems drop from the sky, it always shows "false".
    
if(cpNumber.onkeydown(e) === false) {
    alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Oups...',
        cssClass: 'pop',
        template: '<div class="center-form">This is Wrong !</div>'
    });
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input class="input" 
           type="text" 
           id="cpNumber" 
           maxlength="5" 
           ng-model="cp" 
           placeholder="CP">
</form>
```

Comment: have you added an event listener anywhere in your code?

Comment: No, my code is all here, I thought that ".onkeydown" do it for me. The "e" from ".onkeydown" is create in that function, and also populate in it, so I know I can't call the function like that : if(cpNumber.onkeydown(e) === false), beacause "e" remain unknown... But it's strange because I got a "false" instead of an "undefined"...

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the calls in the blocks themselves. Here's a fiddle for you to look at:

https://jsfiddle.net/tsamzx6h/

```
                          if((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
                              || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58)
                              || ((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
                              || (e.keyCorde == 65)) 
                              || ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
                              || (e.keyCode == 65))
                              || ((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) 
                              || (e.keyCorde == 66)) 
                              || ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58)
                              || (e.keyCode == 66))
                              || e.keyCode == 8)
                            {
                                alert("Good!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert("Wrong");
                            }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working, but I was not clear in my first post, what I'm trying to do is before the form will be validate, check if all keys are right, if not, shows an alert popup. Exemple : 243A3 is entered, the form is validate. DEDK2 is entered, the alert popup is shown.

Comment: Glad to help! If I understand correctly, the way you describe it, you want all letters inside already the input before validating, that will require you to check the length of the letters inside the input before triggering the validation. However that will require regular expression validation already which is outside the scope of your original question.

Comment: Thank you for your help again, I solved the problem, not with a "clean solution", but I used a $scope variable to check if something goes wrong with inputs. And used this variable in my if condition, the one which check the input field before validate the form.

Answer (score 1):

Event cannot be called this way. For making your program functional you can add a function in your else block and call it and do whatever you want. 
PLUS you can also pass your event to function. So that will serve as an added advantage.
HTML:

```
 <form><input class="input" type="text" id="cpNumber" maxlength="5" ng-model="cp" placeholder="CP"></form>
```

Script::

```
ar cpNumber = document.getElementById("cpNumber");


                        cpNumber.onkeydown = function(e) {

                                if((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
                                  || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58)
                                  || ((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
                                  || (e.keyCorde == 65)) 
                                  || ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
                                  || (e.keyCode == 65))
                                  || ((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) 
                                  || (e.keyCorde == 66)) 
                                  || ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58)
                                  || (e.keyCode == 66))
                                  || e.keyCode == 8)
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    notAllowed(e);
                                }
                        };


        // If condition, check if entry keys are wrong. I tried cpNumber.onkeydown(e), but the "e" seems drop from the sky, it always shows "false".

                            function notAllowed (ev) {
                               alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                                    title: 'Oups...',
                                    cssClass: 'pop',
                                    template: '<div class="center-form">This is Wrong !</div>'
                                });
                            }
```

Comment: Also if you are using angular making a directive for all this process would be a much better option,

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is before the form will be validate, check if all keys are right, if not show an alert popup.
Exemple : 243A3 is entered, the form is validate. DEDLK2 is entered, the alert popup is shown.

Comment: For DEDLK2  you need to remove maxlength or change it. Upvote if helpful. Also A syntax mistake was found. Replace  'e.keyCorde == 65' to e.keyCode == 65

Comment: The code you have written will show popup when you type first D in DEDLK2. For making popup happen After full word is written you need to change your logic.

Comment: Oh thank you, didn't see that mistake ! Mmh...Is it possible to send a signal from this function, to another one ?

Comment: Yes. You can use function arguments to communicate btw functions.